# Defining boost_filesystem_version 2?

Tags: c++, boost

I got a lot of code 20-30 files, and I need to compile it with boost_filesystem_version 2. I tried defining it in /include/boost/user.hpp, but it doesnt work. Anyone knows where to define it, or any solution?

Comment: The macro name should be in capitals?

Comment: Have what like what? What does "it doesn't work" mean? There's no question here at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) documentation page: "Version 2 is deprecated, and will not be included in Boost releases 1.48 and later." So if you're using 1.48 or 1.49, you're not getting version 2 back.

Comment: @user1222146: Yes. You were given an entire year or more to do so. 1.44 came out in August of 2010, which was when Version 3 first showed up. The [Boost.Filesystem docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) have told you that Version 2 was going away ever since then. Version 2's support was even extended; it was supposed to go away in 1.46, but they decided to wait until 1.48, to give people more time. It's not like you didn't have fair warning and ample time to make changes.

Comment: @NicolBolas: A year is not a very long time to determine the requirement, scope it out, schedule it, receive allocated time for the work, and to actually do the work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The API did not change *that much*; most of it is just find/replace. If a development team couldn't find time to do it within a full calendar year, then that team needs to be more agile in its development. Also, how would such a team schedule the time to *update* to a new Boost version without checking to see if there were breaking changes?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's not about the team being agile; it's about the stakeholders providing the necessary development time to get to the story, for code changes to work their way up to project trunks, etc etc. I'm not saying that it can't be done in a year, just that "an entire year" isn't necessarily a superlatively massively huge amount of time as you seemed to indicate, unless you're just some hobbyist.

Comment: And I just didn't understand your trailing question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If a development house is so methodical that it takes over a year to recognize the potential problem and allocate maybe a day of programmer time to change to the Filesystem v.3 API, then how long would it take them to upgrade Boost versions? They have other breaking changes in them. They must have allocated time to testing a new version, finding out what the incompatibilities are, and estimating how long it would take to fix. Right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Also, I've seen (and been involved with) entire game engines re-integrated into projects mid-stream within 6 months time. I've personally spent three days dropping in an *entirely new animation system* into a game live in development. So I've got no real sympathy for someone who couldn't run some RegEx find/replaces over a 30 file codebase in a year's time.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Not everybody works for a development house. Some people work within non-development organisations, with tight requirements from stakeholders who have the final say in what your time gets spent on. You can suggest housekeeping work, but ultimately if there's a panicked deadline in six months' time then nobody's going to let you upgrade your API usage.

Comment: And it's a little more than "some RegEx find/replaces"; if the changes are significant, then you've got to rewrite various test procedures and testcases, not to mention run a full test suite again. For some applications, this could be a weeks-long block of work, involving non-software personnel. I'm sure you're very proud of "dropping in an entirely new animation system into a game live in development" in three days, but this sort of rushing is not common. Ceasing support for an API just a year after deprecating it is pretty unusual IMO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "if there's a panicked deadline in six months' time then nobody's going to let you upgrade your API usage." If there's no time to upgrade the API usage, then there's no time to install later versions of Boost. If someone didn't notice the big sign on the docs page saying that the API would be gone in versions 1.48, then that's their fault. Nobody's forcing them to use higher versions of Boost. And ceasing to support an API after a year is far from uncommon in open-source development.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8341/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-lightness-races-in-orbit)

Comment: @NicolBolas: How can they notice the big sign before it's there? The whole point of this discussion is that you only have a year to notice it and do something about it. Again, I'm not saying that it can't be done -- I'm saying that a year isn't a _superlative_ amount of time in which to do it. You seemed to be implying that it's a hugely vast amount of time in which to get the work "done done". Thus I suspect you may not have worked for a large organisation. Am I right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Did you not see the "continue this discussion in chat" sign?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, I did. I wasn't aware that you were the boss of me.